# Symbol name conflicts with new register names in new NASM versions?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, naming, forward-compatibility

Imagine you wrote this 10 years ago (before [Intel MPX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_MPX) and the `bnd0`..`bnd3` registers were even on a roadmap):

```
section .data

; define some globals which are part of an ABI so you can't just rename them
global bnd0      ; MPX bound register name conflict
bnd0: dd 123

global k0        ; AVX512 mask register name conflict
k0: dq 12345
```

**How can you assemble this with a current version of NASM?**  i.e. Does NASM (or YASM) have forward compatibility with new versions that support new register names?

Obviously this is easy to solve with search/replace inside a single file or project.  But in theory, you could have a global variable name as part of a library ABI that you either export from NASM or need to *import* into NASM with `extern ymm0`.  (External symbols have to be declared, so unrecognized register names never assemble to symbol references.)

NASM syntax is already unsuitable as a format for C compiler output on platforms which don't prefix symbol names with an `_` or do some other kind of name mangling (e.g. Linux ELF).  You can't compile a global `int eax = 1;`.  [This is why AT&T syntax uses `%eax` for register names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42244028/what-was-the-original-reason-for-the-design-of-att-assembly-syntax/42250270#42250270).  Discussion in comments on that answer is what inspired this question.  Note that GAS doesn't need external symbols to be declared; unrecognized names are treated as symbols (even in `.intel_syntax noprefix` mode which uses a syntax similar to MASM).

Related: how does MASM handle forward source compatibility for new extensions?

---

**Can you disable MPX support somehow?**

[YASM supports a `CPU` directive](https://www.tortall.net/projects/yasm/manual/html/arch-x86-modes.html#arch-x86-cpu) that lets you disable support for some mnemonics, but even disabling AVX support doesn't let you use `ymm0` as a symbol name.  (YASM 1.3.0 doesn't support AVX512 or MPX, so it can assemble code that uses those register names as symbols, but it does support AVX2.)

```
CPU Conroe
extern ymm0
```

I get `yasm-CPU.asm:2: error: directive 'extern' requires an identifier parameter`.  Or with `ymm0: dd 123`, the error is `yasm-CPU.asm:2: error: label or instruction expected at start of line`

But AVX support is definitely disabled: assembling `CPU Conroe` / `vmovaps xmm0, [edi]` gives:

```
$ yasm -Worphan-labels -felf32 yasm-CPU.asm
yasm-CPU.asm:2: warning: `vmovaps' is an instruction in CPU
yasm-CPU.asm:2: error: instruction expected after label
```

(It says `CPU 686` or similar for older disabled extensions.  IDK why it doesn't say `in CPU Sandybridge AVX`.  It seems that yasm is no longer well maintained.  YASM 1.3.0 supports `CPU Haswell` and `AVX2`, but the docs don't mention it.)

The intent of this feature is to stop you from accidentally using SSE4 instructions in a function for SSSE3-or-lower CPUs, but apparently it doesn't help with this problem.

---

NASM's `CPU` directive seems to be similar, and also doesn't help at all:

```
CPU 686
vmovaps xmm0, [edi]
extern ymm0         
    mov eax, ymm0
```

```
$ nasm -Worphan-labels -felf32 CPU.asm 
CPU.asm:2: error: no instruction for this cpu level
CPU.asm:4: error: invalid combination of opcode and operands
```

Note that it does assemble `extern ymm0` just fine, with or without a `CPU` directive, but as soon as you use it as an operand, you have a problem.

Comment: Side note: apparently even `gcc` can't produce valid code for `int eax=1` with `-masm=intel`. Maybe they should have used `.intel_syntax prefix`. And people keep bashing at&t ... they just don't understand the advantages! :)

Comment: Note that before ELF was introduced, the UNIX assembler didn't use the `%` prefix on x86 as every symbol was prefixed with an underscore.

Comment: @Jester I understand the advantages, I bash AT&T because it's better for computers than for humans. This post just enforces that point of view. :) (and the problem in the question is quite hypothetical, when I was trying to make my old TASM era intros to work, I simply patched them by hand, you usually have just few lines of ASM source to work with, otherwise you have much larger problem than NASM version)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

NASM lets you prefix a symbol with a dollar sign `$` so that it's interpreted as symbol rather than register or other reserved word. From the [NASM documentation](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc3.html):

> #### 3.1 Layout of a NASM Source Line
>
> [...] An identifier may also be prefixed with a `$` to indicate that it is intended to be read as an identifier and not a reserved word; thus, if some other module you are linking with defines a symbol called `eax`, you can refer to `$eax` in NASM code to distinguish the symbol from the register. [...]

MASM is normally only used in environments where C compilers prefix identifiers with underscores `_`, so this isn't as big of an issue with that assembler. However it does have a solution this problem, but it's basically the opposite of NASM's.  You can use the OPTION NOKEYWORD directive to disable reserved words of your choice. For example you can use `OPTION NOKEYWORD:<eax>` so that you can use a symbol named `eax`. Of course that prevents you from using the register named EAX, so it's not as general solution as NASM's.

Comment: Cool.  This might still require a global search/replace to replace `k0` with `$k0` in your asm sources, but that kind of pain is similar to when other languages introduce new keywords.  No wonder the `CPU` directive wasn't doing anything, since the problem is already solved a different way.  I think when I was trying to google an answer, I was using `label` instead of `symbol`.