# Disambiguate labels from register names in the Intel syntax

Tags: assembly, x86, symbols, gnu-assembler, intel-syntax

I'm wondering how to distinguish label names from register names in some instructions in the Intel syntax. For example, `call rdx` usually means an indirect jump, but what if we have a label `rdx` in the same assembly file? I believe it could be interpreted as a direct jump to `rdx`. Is there any notation to tell the assembler which is which?

Comment: What assembler are you programming with?

Comment: I'm using gas at the moment.

Answer (score 5):

It depends on the assembler.

I think for most, **register names take precedence**, so `call rdx` would always be RIP=RDX, without checking for the existence of a label (or extern symbol) of the same name.
**AT&T syntax `call *%rdx`**, not AT&T `call rdx`.

Some assemblers have syntax to disambiguate, **but there's no standard syntax across different assemblers**.

e.g. **for NASM**, this is a duplicate of [Symbol name conflicts with new register names in new NASM versions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45890645) where you can use `$eax` to refer to a symbol / label with the name `eax`, instead of the register.

**For Euroassembler** you can postfix a `:` onto a name to force it to be interpreted as a symbol, not register, like `call rdx:`.  (https://euroassembler.eu/eadoc/#SymbolName),

---

**With GAS `.intel_syntax noprefix`**, you put the symbol name in quotes.  This seems very obscure; I wouldn't recommend GAS Intel-syntax for production use.  It's nice for reading compiler output if you prefer Intel over AT&T syntax, but it has some quirks including this and *[Distinguishing memory from constant in GNU as .intel_syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39355188/distinguishing-memory-from-constant-in-gnu-as-intel-syntax)* which make it a worse Intel-syntax than NASM.

```
.intel_syntax noprefix
rdx:
call rdx            # call reg
call "rdx"          # call rel32

mov eax, [rip + "rdx"]    # rip-relative load of that machine code
mov eax, ["rdx" + rdx]    # use the register as an offset from the symbol
# mov eax, [rip + rdx]    # error: RIP-relative doesn't work with other regs
```

Then we can disassemble in AT&T syntax just to be extra clear / unambiguous about what we got.

```
$ gcc -c gas-symbol.s && objdump -drwC -Matt gas-symbol.o

...
0000000000000000 <rdx>:
   0:   ff d2                   call   *%rdx
   2:   e8 f9 ff ff ff          call   0 <rdx>
   7:   8b 05 f3 ff ff ff       mov    -0xd(%rip),%eax        # 0 <rdx>
   d:   8b 82 00 00 00 00       mov    0x0(%rdx),%eax   f: R_X86_64_32S .text
```

The RIP-relative version resolved at assemble time since the symbol was defined by a label in the same file.  The `disp32(%rdx)` is waiting for the linker to fill in the absolute address, which [will only work in a non-PIE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43367427/32-bit-absolute-addresses-no-longer-allowed-in-x86-64-linux).

BTW, the relocation info (printed by `-r`) only shows `.text`  instead of the symbol name `rdx`, unlike the relative branch and the RIP-relative load.  The relative addressing is fully resolved at assemble time, no actual relocation for the linker to fill in, so printing `<rdx>` is just informational.  But the absolute address for `[symbol + reg]` has a relocation entry, and objdump is printing the symbol name it used, perhaps.  If I use `.globl rdx` to make that symbol fully visible in the symbol table, it will print `rdx-0x4` instead of `.text`.

---

Intel-syntax is a bit of a 2nd-class citizen behind AT&T syntax in the GNU toolchain.  GCC doesn't bother to use quotes, so compiling C that uses an `int eax;` global variable with `gcc -masm=intel` will make it emit a `.s` which GAS chokes on!  (Assuming a target ABI like i386 or x86-64 System V that doesn't decorate C symbol names with leading underscores; `_eax` avoids problems, e.g. on macOS or 32-bit Windows.)

You could in theory (and maybe just for a few lines) use `.intel_syntax prefix` so `%rdx` is still required on register names while bare `rdx` is interpreted as a symbol, but that's an evil mutant hybrid that will break people's brains when they look at `sub %ecx, %eax` and assume it's AT&T syntax because of the `%` decorators.  Also, it's not even supported by clang's assembler: only `.att_syntax prefix` and `.intel_syntax noprefix`.  For good reason, because nobody should use this abomination of syntax.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any notation to tell the assembler which is which?

This depends on the assembler you use. There is no common syntax to do so.

However some assemblers have features to distinguish labels from reserved words. For example the [section "3.1 Layout of a NASM Source Line" in the nasm documentation](https://nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc3.html) states, that you can prefix your label with a `$` to distinguish it from the register:

> An identifier may also be prefixed with a `$` to indicate that it is intended to be read as an identifier and not a reserved word; thus, if some other module you are linking with defines a symbol called eax, you can refer to `$eax` in NASM code to distinguish the symbol from the register