# Use of parentheses in gnu ATT GAS

Tags: assembly, cpu-registers, att

I have a question concerning parentheses in GAS. I have looked in SO and in quite a few number of other places, but I am still unclear on this:

What is the difference between?:

```
movl %edx, %eax
```

and

```
movl (%edx), %eax
```

From my understanding, parentheses dereference the address stored at the register.

|  | register | value | value at address |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | `%edx` | `0x00` | 20 |
| 2 | `%edx` | int 20 | whatever is located at `0x14` (int 20) ? |

I am understanding this as follows:

- # 1: an address is stored in the register

  - `%edx == 0x00` and `(%edx) == 20`
- # 2: a value is store in register

  - `%edx == 20` and `(%edx) ==` *whatever is at `0x14`*, which would probably segfault if attempted to access.

Can someone please elaborate on what the parentheses are doing and if I am seeing this correctly?

Comment: Parentheses are confusingly used both for grouping in arithmetic expressions and for indices.  Their presence does not indicate a memory operand, e.g. `$(42)` is an immediate operand without indirection.  I have previously written [a bit more on that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77381955/417501).

Comment: Note also that fundamentally, the syntax can only let you do things the hardware can do.  So read up on what addressing modes x86-64 supports and then see how they map to AT&T syntax.  If there's no addressing mode to express a certain operand, it cannot be used, even if you could think of a syntax that looks like it would do so.

Comment: For your first question (please avoid asking multiple questions in one Stack Overflow question), the answer is “option 2” if I understood your confusingly worded table correctly.  Addresses are just numbers, so not sure why you distinguish them.  For (2), again, read up on what addressing modes x86 supports.  Most addressing modes only involve general purpose registers, though scatter/gather instructions do involve SIMD registers, too.

Comment: Yes.  In assembly, pointers are just integers, so you're correct, accessing absolute address `20` will normally fault if running under a normal OS, unless you've taken special steps to map the lowest page.  (e.g. changed https://wiki.debian.org/mmap_min_addr and used `mmap(MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS)` with a hint address to allocate that page.)  In the table in your question, the bare `%edx` talks about a "value" and a "value at address".  That doesn't make sense, there isn't any memory addressing happening.  The 3-bit register number in the machine code gets the CPU to use a reg value directly