# What does % mean on register names in assembly language?

Tags: assembly, syntax, x86, att, intel-syntax

I tried to convert and interpret C language code into assembly language with GCC -S option.
What is the difference between `push %rbp` and `push rbp`?

Comment: `gcc -masm=intel` will use Intel syntax, the default is `-masm=att`.  Pick whichever you find easier to read.  See [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38552116)

Answer (score 3):

Both statements you gave do the same thing, the main difference is in the syntax.
There are 2 major syntax conventions for X86, the Intel convention and the AT&T convention.
See [syntax comparison](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_assembly_language#Syntax) for details.

**[UPD:]** Just in case, duplicating the syntax information here:

|  | AT&T | Intel |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **Parameter order** | Source before the destination. `movl $5, %eax` | Destination before source. `mov eax, 5` |
| **Parameter size** | Mnemonics are suffixed with a letter indicating the size of the operands: **q** for qword, **l** for long (dword), **w** for word, and **b** for byte. `addl $4, %esp` | Derived from the name of the register that is used (e.g. **rax**, **eax**, **ax**, **al** imply **q**, **l**, **w**, **b**, respectively). `add esp, 4` |
| [**Sigils**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigil_(computer_programming)) | [Immediate values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_(computer_programming)) prefixed with a **$**, registers prefixed with a **%**. | The assembler automatically detects the type of symbols; i.e., whether they are registers, constants or something else. |
| **Effective addresses** | General syntax of DISP(BASE,INDEX,SCALE). `movl mem_addr(%ebx,%ecx,4), %eax` | Arithmetic expressions in square brackets; additionally, size keywords like **byte**, **word**, or **dword** have to be used if the size cannot be determined from the operands. `mov eax, [ebx + ecx*4 + mem_addr]` |

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/intel-syntax/info and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/att/info have similar info and syntax examples.  Both linked from https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info

Answer (score 1):

In AT&T syntax, `push rbp` would be a push of a memory operand, with symbol name `rbp`, like if you compiled some C code that used `long rbp;` as a global variable.

`rbp` doesn't have a `%` so the assembler knows you aren't referring to the register of the same name; that's how AT&T syntax disambiguates this case.  If you do want the register, you *must* use `%` like `%rbp`.

- [Questions about AT&T x86 Syntax design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4193827/questions-about-att-x86-syntax-design/35817580#35817580)
- [What was the original reason for the design of AT&T assembly syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42244028/what-was-the-original-reason-for-the-design-of-att-assembly-syntax)

`rbp` is an absolute addressing mode; normally you'd use `pushq rbp(%rip)` if you actually wanted to push the contents of a global.  Push-memory with any other addressing mode looks like `pushq (%rdi, %rsi, 8)`.  In 32-bit code it is normal to access global variables with their bare symbol name, like `mov foo, %eax` to load from one.

---

But more likely you meant `push rbp` as the Intel-syntax version of `push %rbp`, pushing the register like a normal person.

**`gcc -masm=intel` will use Intel syntax**, the default is `-masm=att`. Pick whichever you find easier to read. See [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38552116/how-to-remove-noise-from-gcc-clang-assembly-output)

For more details on syntax differences, see @hidefromkgb's answer, and:

- https://stackoverflow.com/tags/intel-syntax/info
- https://stackoverflow.com/tags/att/info
- Both are linked from https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info which has lots of useful links to manuals and guides.

Comment: @SepRoland: That answer is assuming `push rbp` is Intel-syntax (which is almost certainly what was intended, unless they just manually stripped the `%`).  But good point, updated.